# Disabling years range using Pickadate.js date picker

Tags: jquery, pickadate

I'm trying to alter the years displayed in dropdown using the [Pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js) but can't get it working. As of now the year dropdown list contains years that I don't want to see including the current year. Question is, how can I remove a range of years like I want to just display year `1910 - 2012`.

This is what I have so far:

```
 $('.datepicker').pickadate({
          selectMonths: true,
          selectYears: 80,
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          max : false,
          today: '',
          clear: 'Clear Selection',
          onStart: function() {
        $('.picker__select--month').attr('name', 'month');
        $('.picker__day--selected').attr('name', 'day');
        $('.picker__select--year').attr('name', 'year');
    },
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, it will set years 1910 - to dec 2012 or how do you need dynamic:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
          selectMonths: true,
          selectYears: 200,
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          min: new Date(1910,1,1),
          max: new Date(2012,11,31),
          today: '',
          clear: 'Clear Selection',
          onStart: function() {
        $('.picker__select--month').attr('name', 'month');
        $('.picker__day--selected').attr('name', 'day');
        $('.picker__select--year').attr('name', 'year');
    },
 });
```

Comment: I don't want to display current year. I want just 1910 until 2012.

Comment: then there is need to specify max value for it like `max: new Date(2012,11,31),` that is 31 december 2012; there was option to set min. and max date to choose.

Comment: I set max value and it displays the correct output.

Comment: Thanks man! I'll accept this one. Got confusion about the dates. Additionaly we can use disable to target the date we won't include.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#limits):

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  min: new Date(1910,1,1),
  max: new Date(2012,1,1)
});
```

If you're okay to specify the date for the certain years you want to limit to.

It's fine to use arrays too:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  min: [1910,1,1],
  max: [2012,1,1]
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but can we make it dynamic? or like just the year we set not including the day and month?

Comment: Dynamic.. get current year `new Date().getFullYear()` .. try this for `max` and why would the date be an issue since 1st of January 1910 includes the whole year.. try to specify without dates

Comment: hmm. but only year we can't specify there for options min. and max.

Comment: Issue is it wont allow to choose until December in the month when in 2012 year

Comment: @urbz, you got the main solution bro, but there's a lil bit issue on the max date from the answer you provide.